How to do cudaMemcpy with priority
Objective:
I have two groups of data that need to be copied to the GPU. The first group is large and has a lower priority, while the second one is smaller and has a higher priority, such as metadata for a new job. The cudaMemcpyAsync() of the low-priority one is issued first. I want to ensure that the higher-priority data copy can preempt the lower-priority one.
Attempted Solution:
To achieve this, I created two CUDA streams with different priorities: one with high priority and the other with low priority. Then, I used cudaMemcpyAsync() to copy the data on the streams based on their priorities. Below is a code example illustrating this approach:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    cudaStream_t high, low;
    // Get CUDA priority range
    int low_priority_range, high_priority_range;
    cudaDeviceGetStreamPriorityRange(&low_priority_range, &high_priority_range);
    printf("low_priority_range: %d, high_priority_range: %d\n",
           low_priority_range,
           high_priority_range);
    // Create streams with different priorities
    cudaStreamCreateWithPriority(&low, cudaStreamNonBlocking, low_priority_range);
    cudaStreamCreateWithPriority(&high, cudaStreamNonBlocking, high_priority_range);
    cudaEvent_t start, stop, start1, stop1;
    cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&start1); cudaEventCreate(&stop); cudaEventCreate(&stop1);
    void *host1, *host2;
    cudaMallocHost(&host1, 1024ll * 1024 * 1024 * 2); // Allocate host memory for large dataset
    cudaMallocHost(&host2, 1024); // Allocate host memory for small dataset
    void *device1, *device2;
    cudaMalloc(&device1, 1024ll * 1024 * 1024 * 2); // Allocate device memory for large dataset
    cudaMalloc(&device2, 1024); // Allocate device memory for small dataset
    cudaEventRecord(start1, low); // Record start time for low-priority stream
    // Copy large dataset to GPU using low-priority stream
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cudaMemcpyAsync(device1, host1, 1024ll * 1024 * 1024 * 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, low);
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop1, low); // Record stop time for low-priority stream
    cudaEventRecord(start, high); // Record start time for high-priority stream
    // Copy small dataset to GPU using high-priority stream
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cudaMemcpyAsync(device2, host2, 1024, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, high);
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, high); // Record stop time for high-priority stream
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    float high_priority_stream_time, low_priority_stream_time;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&high_priority_stream_time, start, stop); // Calculate elapsed time for high-priority stream
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&low_priority_stream_time, start1, stop1); // Calculate elapsed time for low-priority stream
    printf("high priority stream time: %f ms\n", high_priority_stream_time);
    printf("low priority stream time: %f ms\n", low_priority_stream_time);
    return 0;
}

Current Outcome and Question:
Upon testing the code on my platform (A30), I observed that both streams took almost the same amount of time, indicating that the cudaMemcpyAsync() on the high-priority stream occurred after the low-priority stream.
My question is: How can I ensure that the cudaMemcpyAsync() issued later is executed with higher priority, i.e., it occurs before the cudaMemcpyAsync() on the other stream performing background copying?

cuda stream priority has no impact on cudaMemcpyAsync issued into a particular stream.  To guarantee that a copy A occurs before a copy B (using a cudaMemcpy... variant) it would be necessary to issue copy A prior to copy B, into the same stream as copy B.    It might be possible to do something like this with copy kernels in lieu of cudaMemcpy... API calls (and using stream priority), but I don't have anything to offer at this time beyond that statement.  Because of the nature of GPU greedy execution, it is often difficult to witness stream priority the way one might think or expect.

Very much thanks for your suggestion! In my case, the GPU is still busy computing, so I can't use a kernel to copy it. I have an ugly workaround for it. The high-priority task will grab a lock when it needs to copy. Running a background thread to do low-priority copy jobs one by one, with a check of the lock in between. Hope to hear more graceful solutions :(

Using a copy-kernel for the small, high-priority stuff while using cudaMemcpyAsync for the large, low-priority copy seems like a relatively elegant solution although one would have to check if it is actually as good or better than your workaround. Assuming that by small you mean small enough that one only needs one or a few blocks for a short duration, the influence on the performance of some big compute kernel might be manageable. Although this also assumes that the big kernel actually frequently repopulates SMs with new blocks instead of optimizing for a single wave of blocks.
